# XMLHttpRequest response is null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

when trying to execute XMLHttpRequest, the response is returned from server (as checked in Fiddler), but xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() returns null and throws exception.

Is it because of "Same Origin Policy"? Can you please suggest how to resolve the issue?

Code: Using datajs.codeplex.com open source code:

```
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr === null || xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                    return;
                }

                // Workaround for XHR behavior on IE.
                var statusText = xhr.statusText;
                var statusCode = xhr.status;
                if (statusCode === 1223) {
                    statusCode = 204;
                    statusText = "No Content";
                }

                var headers = [];
                var responseHeaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().split(/\r?\n/);
```

Resource is located in different domain. Accessing http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Genres

Comment: An example of some code would help answer what might be wrong.

Comment: Please post code sample.  It sounds as if your checking the response before they've been returned.

Comment: The same-origin policy only applies if you try to access resources *not* located at your domain. As you don't specify what you are trying to access, the answer is: Maybe.

Comment: @geoffreyd @leeeb Code: Using datajs.codeplex.com open source code.
                   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr === null || xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var headers = [];
                    var responseHeaders = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().split(/\r?\n/);

throws exception xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() is null

Comment: Same origin policy blocks cross-domain XHR. Also, keep in mind that if the status code is 1223/204 (even same-origin), the getAllResponseHeaders call returns null.

Answer (score 0):

If the The same-origin policy is your problem, you could use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) as a proxy.

EDIT: eg. [http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20atom%2810%29%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Genres%27](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20atom%2810%29%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A//odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Genres%27)

What's nice is that you can ask to get the result as json and consume it easily from your client script.

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent the same-origin policy you could use JS to call a PHP script that gets the contents of the external url and `echo` the results.